# How do I SET the GOPATH environment variable on Ubuntu? What file must I edit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go

I am trying to do a `go get`:

```
go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

and it fails with the following error:

```
package github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

when I do a `go env` , a list of Go values is shown as below:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-x-xx-x:~$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

clearly the GOPATH is not set, how and where do I set it?

I see many threads that mention this error but none that provide an answer to my question, which file needs to be edited to provide a value for this path?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: In addition to the answers on what to set it as, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24306485/2668831), which clarifies what the GOPATH is, and how it should be used in general

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables

Comment: Use GVM: https://github.com/moovweb/gvm

Comment: I recommend reading the answer to a more general question. I point out where to set GOPATH variable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962251/450989

Comment: Note: Go 1.8+ (Q2 2017) will set `GOPATH` for you: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40238414/6309).

Comment: `go env -w GOPATH=/where/you/want`

Answer (score 378):

**New Way:**

[Check out this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026674/115363)

Note: Not for trying out a go application / binaries on your host machine using `go install [repo url]`, in such cases you still have to use the old way.

**Old Way:**

Just add the following lines to `~/.bashrc` and this will persist. However, you can use other paths you like as GOPATH instead of `$HOME/go` in my sample.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: The path was `/usr/share/go` on mine Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: However using `/usr/share/go` somehow crippled `go build`: `runtime: exec: "/usr/share/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g": stat /usr/share/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g: no such file or directory` so i am not really sure what's the right setup

Comment: Do NOT use /usr/share/go.  GOPATH is go's "workspace", where it downloads packages, et cetera.   Create a new directory and use that.   I recommend ~/.go

Comment: The path was `/usr/share/go` on mine Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Just a simple reminder: In order for these changes to take effect, don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc` if you want to use these variables immediately in your current terminal window. Otherwise you'll need to start a new terminal (or otherwise trigger processing of your `~/.bashrc` file for example by logging out and in again).

Comment: As stated in user2128535's answer, GOROOT should be set to /usr/lib/go

Comment: Do not set GOROOT!  http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really

Comment: Remember to `$ source ~/.bashrc` ;)

Comment: This only works if your shell is bash, you really should use `/etc/environment` so `chsh` doesn't break it. Restart is required.

Comment: for zsh the line should be added to `~/.zshrc`

Comment: New way is only for projects, if you're installing go application using `go install` you still have to use old way.

Comment: Don't forget to add exports to .bashrc or .zshrc like this:

echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/go' >> ~/.bashrc &&
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin' >> ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 132):

#### New Way: Go Modules

Since Go 1.11, you don't have to use GOPATH anymore. Simply go to your project directory and do this once:

```
go mod init github.com/youruser/yourrepo
```

- With this, Go creates a module root at that directory.
- You can create as many modules as you want.
- For step by step instructions, also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838469/how-to-compile-go-program-consisting-of-multiple-files/61793820#61793820).

---

#### Old Way: GOPATH

If you insist on working with GOPATH then heed this:

- Since Go 1.8, you don't need to set your GOPATH or GOROOT.
- GOPATH by default is under your user/home directory.

[From the documentation](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH):

> If no GOPATH is set, it is assumed to be $HOME/go on Unix systems and %USERPROFILE%\go on Windows. If you want to use a custom location as your workspace, you can set the GOPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 68):

Ubuntu 14.04

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

Additionally you can add this string to file

```
$HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: Your comment is confusing because it is referring to a now removed line of the original answer.

Comment: mkdir -p ~/go/bin
export GOPATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin:

Answer (score 67):

GOPATH should be set to a newly created empty directory.   This is the go "workspace", where it downloads packages, et cetera.   I use ~/.go.

For example:

```
mkdir ~/.go
echo "GOPATH=$HOME/.go" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export GOPATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "PATH=\$PATH:\$GOPATH/bin # Add GOPATH/bin to PATH for scripting" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

source:  http://www.larry-price.com/blog/2013/12/15/setting-up-a-go-environment-in-ubuntu-12-dot-04/

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 45):

If for example, it is an Ubuntu, after installing the packages:

```
$sudo apt install golang -y
```

Just add the following lines to ~/.bashrc (Of your user)

```
export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: thanks, i just uninstalled my previous installation (not used apt that time) and did what u have provided. works all good thanks :>

Answer (score 22):

Write this code in Terminal.

```
export GOPATH=path/to/your/gopath/directory
```

**Note**: This will reset on every new Terminal window or system restart.

To be persistent, paste the code below in your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` file according to your shell. Those files in your **Home Directory**. It will be like below.

```
export PATH=path/to/some/other/place/composer/for/example
export GOPATH=path/to/your/gopath/directory
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Answer (score 20):

```
export GOPATH=/path/desired/here
```

There is no need to edit any file, we can just use the command above to directly edit the Go environment variables.

Comment: This isn't persistent though. If you want this option to stay - you likely do - you'll have to add it to some file that's being loaded on login.

Comment: Thanks! What most users don't ever think is that there are people starting with linux and if there is no documentation saying what you said(Because everybody thinks it's a known fact) how would we learn/find the information?

Answer (score 13):

For **Go 1.13+**:

```sh
go env -w GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

To set the GOPATH regardless of the GO version add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

and don't forget to source your `.bashrc` file:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

More options on the `golang` official wiki:
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH

Answer (score 12):

You will need GOPATH later, too. So add it to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Yes, I had this in mind, but dismissed the possibility that a guy would have an Ubuntu box with a custom shell and not know it as highly unlikely :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you've setup anything that needs modification of environment variables e.g. Java, Go etc this will be very familiar.

I will assume that you have the following directory structure somewhere as your Go path:

```
\---[folder name]
    +---bin
    +---pkg
    \---src
```

- open a new terminal
- type `sudo nano /etc/environment`
- find `PATH=...` and go the end of it and add a colon `:` after the last path then paste in your full `go path` e.g. `/home/user/gocode`

and you're done, This should make it persistent through the system.

Comment: I don't see why change $PATH if go is working for David. He needs to set $GOPATH (see the answer from Daniel Lin). David may merge both approaches (or set it in /etc/profile or $HOME/.profile). By the way, I recommend David to read these links: http://golang.org/doc/install and http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

Comment: @zk82 $GOPATH is an environment variable, and I don't see why editing your environment variables to add this variable to it a problem. Same goes for $JAVA_HOME and other frameworks that require such configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the following lines to **~/.bashrc**

```
export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: I'm using mac pro 16 (Intel) Big Sur with golang version 1.17.6, worked fine for me, updated in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` then `source .bashrc`

Answer (score 4):

```
export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

And you may want to check by 
$ go env

Answer (score 3):

This is what got it working for me on **Ubuntu 15.10** using the `fish shell`:

```
# ~/.config/fish/config.fish

set -g -x PATH /usr/local/bin $PATH
set -g -x GOPATH /usr/share/go
```

Then I had to change the permissions on the `go` folder (it was set to root)

```
sudo chown <name>:<name> -R /usr/share/go
```

Answer (score 3):

go path could be every where you want just create a directory and set global path variable in the name of GOPATH to your environment.

```
mkdir ~/go
export GOPATH=~/go
go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

**GOPATH** is an environment variable to your work-space location. 
**GOROOT** is an environment variable to your installation directory. Although **GOROOT** and **GOPATH** is automatically set (if there would not be a bug) during the installation time, to specify it manually you can follow below process. Moreover, for more information you can refer to [GO's wiki page](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH).

It is better to set **GOPATH** to a directory inside your home directory, e.g., $HOME/go, %USERPROFILE%\go (Windows).

1. This is a solution mac, which is tested on macOS Sierra, ver. 10.12, and also in Gogland-EAP, which has been introduced as an IDE for Go programming by JetBrains.

On your Terminal type

```
vim ~/.profile
```

in opened document on the Terminal press **i** and add the following path

```
GOPATH=/path/to/a/directory/inside/home/directory
GOROOT=/path/to/you/go/library
PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH:$GOROOT:$GOROOT/bin
```

press **ESC** and type **:x**.
Lastly, you should restart (**close** and **open**) your terminal or **Logout** and **Login** again.

2. For Windows and Linux configuration, please refer to Go wiki page at Githab on [Setting GOPATH-Golang](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Setting-GOPATH).

*CAUTION* Do not set both **GOROOT** and **GOPATH** to the same directory, otherwise you will get a warning.

Answer (score 3):

(Ubuntu)

If you don’t set a GOPATH, the default will be used.

You have to add $GOPATH/bin to your PATH to execute any binary installed in $GOPATH/bin, or you need to type $GOPATH/bin/the-command. 
Add this to your ~/.bash_profile

> `export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH`

Current GOPATH command:

> `go env GOPATH`

Changing the GOPATH command:

> `export GOPATH=$HOME/your-desired-path`

Answer (score 2):

With Go 1.8 (Q2 2017), you won't have to edit any file if you accept the default `GOPATH` value (set for you)

```
$HOME/go
```

You can see the comments on [issue 17262](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17262) and the [associated twitter vote](https://twitter.com/golang/status/781189567437164544):

> By choosing a default `GOPATH`, we can make our documentation easier because we can say things like

```
$ go get github.com/foo/bar
```

> will check out the `github.com/foo/bar` repo into `$HOME/go/src/github.com/foo/bar`.
>
> We don't need to distract newcomers with having to set an env var, all we need to do is put a little parenthetical note at the bottom of the page
>
> > `$HOME/go` is the default path to your go workspace.
> >     If you want to change this path, set the `GOPATH` variable to something of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

My go environment looked similar to yours.

```
$go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.6"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

I resolved it with setting GOPATH to **/usr/lib/go**. Try it out.

```
export GOPATH=/usr/lib/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: I read somewhere that setting GOPATH as the same as the installation directory is a bad idea. O.o

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the ~.profile file add::

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using zsh :

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

then add to the end of the file :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

finally :

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

and open a new terminal

```
go version
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been the most annoying thing to deal with. In hopes of saving your time.

IF go was installed as root user. The root user of your system's bash_profile text file ~/.bash_profile needs to have $GOROOT assigned to the go install directory and $GOPATH needs to be assigned to go /src directory.

```
  ...$# sudo su
  ...$# vi ~/.bash_profile

    ***Story continues in vi editor***

    GOROOT=$GOROOT:/usr/local/go
    GOPATH=$GOPATH:/usr/local/go/src
    ...
    [your regular PATH stuff here]
    ...
```

***be sure the path to go binary is in your path on .bash_profile***

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin

This PATH can be as long a string it needs to be..to add new items just separate by colon :

***exit vi editor and saving bash profile (:wq stands for write and quit)***

```
  [esc] 
  [shift] + [:] 
  :wq
```

You have to log out of terminal and log back in for profile to initiate again..or you can just kick start it by using export.

```
...$# export GOPATH=/usr/local/go/src
```

You can verify go env:

```
...$# go env
```

Yay!

```
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/usr/local/go/src"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

Now you can sudo and go will be able to download and create directories inside go/src and you can get down to what you were trying to get done.

example

```
# sudo go get github.com/..
```

Now you will run into another problem..you might not have git installed..that's another adventure..:)

Comment: **Don't do this.** You do **not** want to compile things as root and you do **not** want `go get` to put anything anywhere near `GOROOT`.

Comment: How does one run go under a normal user? Thanks so much. Things weren't working out during install process and I ended up using a test virtual machine to try out GO.

Answer (score 0):

On my Fedora 20 machine I added the following lines to my ~/.bashrc:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/lib/golang
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: [Don't set `GOROOT`](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really). (Unless you're in the extremely small subset of people that uses a binary distribution of Go but install it somewhere where non-standard.)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution: Export every `GO*` environment variable from `go env`

**.bashrc:**

```sh
eval $(go env | grep '^GO[A-Z0-9_]*=' | while read setenv; do
  echo "export $setenv; "
done 2> /dev/null)

[[ -n $GOPATH ]] || export GOPATH="$HOME/go/bin"
[[ -n $GOROOT ]] || export GOROOT=/usr/bin/go
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin"
```

Comment: `eval` is usually a bad idea and an overkill in this situation IMHO

Comment: @PawełPrażak Why? (I'm no expert in shell script)

Comment: if there's a bug in what's being evaluated, the consequences can be painful; here the question was how to export `GOPATH` only

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `~/.bash_profile` to add the following line:

```
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/work
```

Save and exit your editor. Then, source your `~/.bash_profile`

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Note: Set the GOBIN path to generate a binary file when go install is run

```
$ export GOBIN=$HOME/work/bin
```

Answer (score -1):

This script will help you switch Gopaths. https://github.com/buffonomics/goswitch

Comment: Do not blindly share a script. Shell out a mention of its use case and scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "export" solution just like what other guys have suggested. I'd like to provide you with another solution for permanent convenience: you can use any path as GOPATH when running Go commands.

Firstly, you need to download a small tool named `gost` : https://github.com/byte16/gost/releases . If you use ubuntu, you can download the linux version(https://github.com/byte16/gost/releases/download/v0.1.0/gost_linux_amd64.tar.gz).

Then you need to run the commands below to unpack it :

```
$ cd /path/to/your/download/directory 
$ tar -xvf gost_linux_amd64.tar.gz
```

You would get an executable `gost`.  You can move it to `/usr/local/bin` for convenient use:

```
$ sudo mv gost /usr/local/bin
```

Run the command below to add the path you want to use as GOPATH into the **pathspace** `gost` maintains. It is required to give the path a name which you would use later.

```
$ gost add foo /home/foobar/bar     # 'foo' is the name and '/home/foobar/bar' is the path
```

Run any Go command you want in the format:

```
gost goCommand [-p {pathName}] -- [goFlags...] [goArgs...]
```

For example, you want to run `go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` with `/home/foobar/bar` as the GOPATH, just do it as below:

```
$ gost get -p foo -- github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql  # 'foo' is the name you give to the path above.
```

It would help you to set the GOPATH and run the command. But remember that you have added the path into `gost`'s **pathspace**. If you are under any level of subdirectories of `/home/foobar/bar`, you can even just run the command below which would do the same thing for short :

```
$ gost get -- github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

`gost` is a Simple Tool of Go which can help you to manage GOPATHs and run Go commands. For more details about how to use it to run other Go commands, you can just run `gost help goCmdName`. For example you want to know more about `install`, just type words below in:

```
$ gost help install
```

You can also find more details in the README of the project: https://github.com/byte16/gost/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score -1):

You have to update the PATH based on the terminal(bash or zsh) which you use.

1. Open the shell script file of the terminal i.e `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` in an editor

> ```
>    vi ~/.zshrc
>       (or)
>    code ~/.zshrc
> ```

2. Update the below GOPATH if already found or add the below line.

`export GOPATH=$HOME/go:/$HOME/projects/go`

Here you can add one or more paths separated by a semicolon `:` from different locations of your GO projects on the system to the `GOPATH` environment variable i.e `/path/1:path/2:path/3` etc.

In my case, I have added 2 paths, as shown above, one from the root `$HOME/go` and the other one from the projects directory `:/$HOME/projects/go`

Answer (score -2):

As written in the [official instructions](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH):

> The GOPATH environment variable specifies the location of your workspace. It defaults to a directory named go inside your home directory, so $HOME/go on Unix, $home/go on Plan 9, and %USERPROFILE%\go (usually C:\Users\YourName\go) on Windows. If you would like to work in a different location, you will need to set GOPATH to the path to that directory. (Another common setup is to set GOPATH=$HOME.) Note that GOPATH must not be the same path as your Go installation.

So for example, if you are coding in Jetbrains Webstorm (using the [Go plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9568-go)), you might want to set `GOPATH` as `/Users/<user>/WebstormProjects`.

In simpler words, set it to wherever you want your Go projects to reside.