# gvm setting GOPATH in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: go, revel, gvm

I installed `gvm` with `go1.3`, what next? I'm trying to build `Revel`, but I have the error:

```
can't load package: package github.com/robfig/revel/cmd: cannot find package "github.com/robfig/revel/cmd" in any of:
    /home/cnaize/.gvm/gos/go1.3/src/pkg/github.com/robfig/revel/cmd (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/21012349/749854 (are you unsing linux?)

Comment: If you follow the above comment: Don't set GOROOT. It's already set. You will need to set (and export) GOPATH.

Comment: my `bashrc` file looks like this `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "/home/cnaize/.gvm/scripts/gvm" ]] && source "/home/cnaize/.gvm/scripts/gvm"

export GOPATH=$HOME/Dropbox/develop/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin`, but it doesn't work

Comment: Check this gvm issue: https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues/189

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the `gvm` package with `pkgset`

```
  gvm install go1.2.2
  gvm use go1.2.2
  gvm pkgset create revel-test
  gvm pkgset use revel-test
  go get github.com/reve/revel/cmd/revel
```

Comment: canu remove the . from the first line : go.1.2.2. -> go1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

after gvm install #version run:

```
 gvm use #version
```

Comment: You might also want to setup a default in case you haven't: gvm use go1.6.3 --default. It seem if you don't have a default set gvm will blank your GOPATH

Comment: Thanks for adding the comment about using the `--default` flag, this was missing for me.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set your `GOPATH` environment variable by running a command like this

```
export GOPATH=/path/to/your/go/workspace
```

then get the package, by using the command

```
go get github.com/robfig/revel/cmd
```

Note if you set your `GOPATH` in `.bashrc`, you have to `source ~/.bashrc` to make it effective the first time (or re-open your terminal).

I suggest you also read some documentation or tutorial about go instead of just creating a new question each time you do something. A list of resources is available on the [go tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info).

Comment: I used to do this, but it doesn't work, that's why I've created this post

Comment: Your error message distincly claim that `GOPATH` isn't set. So being by checking your `GOPATH`.

Comment: gvm will take over managing GOPATH as well, overriding whatever value you have defined in your environment. If you'd set your GOPATH in .bashrc  and that was working, and now you are using gvm then "it doesn't work" makes sense.