# Is it one project per gopath?

Tags: go

I am really enjoying the Go language but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the gopath rules and constraints.

I spun up a project on my desktop as a non-committal experiment, wanting to pull in a few dependencies. Quickly learned that it didn't work that way. Even when working on a project within my GOPATH, all of my paths must be absolutes from the gopath /src.

Does this mean the gopath is for one project? Should I be changing my gopath frequently (when moving between projects)?

Comment: no, one gopath for all of your projects. All of you projects should live somewhere in `$GOPATH/src`. E.g. `$GOPATH/src/project_foo` is ok, and `$GOPATH/src/github.com/davidalsh/project_bar` is ok also.

Comment: I have a monorepo with a couple of nested go projects. Would I have to ferry them back and forth to ensure they build correctly?

Comment: ferry them to where? You mean import them into other projects?

Comment: Just import them using the path starting after `src` i.e. `import "project_foo"` and `import "github.com/davidalsh/project_bar"` for importing the example packages from the first comment

Comment: When eventually you deploy your package you should vendor any packages that live outside of the one you're deploying. If `project_bar` imports `project_foo`, you need to vendor `project_foo`. You do this with a dependency manager like `govendor` or `dep`

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. my gopath is `~/go` and I have a large repo which has multiple projects (clients, and other servers), that lives in `~/development/large-repo`. If I want to work on the go projects inside the large-repo, would I need to copy/paste them into my gopath, then back when I want to commit my changes?

Comment: You should move `large-repo` somewhere into `~/go/src/` and work from there. No need to have it also in `~/development/`, that is, unless you have some other constraints which require that the `large-repo` lives in `~/development`.

Comment: But then I would also have separate project types/languages in there. Like unrelated web client files (JavaScript and such)

Comment: What would be the problem with that?

Comment: Nothing majorly, I suppose. Feels a bit messy to fracture my development folder organisation based on language. Thanks for the answers though. Is the gopath pattern unique to Go?

Comment: Not sure if it's unique, but it's definitely something you can get used to however unusual it may seem at first. Also it's possible that the feeling of messiness is caused more by the original structure of the *large* repo than by the gopath constraint... so maybe, just maybe, it's an indicator that the large repo is a bit too large.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explain why GOPATH is convenient and how it should be used in general?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306183/can-someone-explain-why-gopath-is-convenient-and-how-it-should-be-used-in-genera)