# What is the reason to have GOPATH set to my workspace?

Tags: go, package, gopath

I read everywhere that my `GOPATH` must be set to my workspace. If I do that and use `go get` to get packages from for example GitHub, they are all added to my workspace though, which I don't find particularly useful because it clutters my workspace. In my workspace I expect to find MY code and my code only.

So I now have my own repos in `~/repos/go` and left my `GOPATH` to be the default `~/go`. This works perfect. All libraries I import live in `~/go`, which keeps my own workplace `~/repos/go` nice and clean. This works great for me, so I'm not sure why this is not the recommended way of working.

Am I missing something? Are there things I break or are functionalities not working in this way?

### Edit

To explain why my question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306183/can-someone-explain-why-gopath-is-convenient-and-how-it-should-be-used-in-genera): I know what `GOPATH` does (define a place to put packages when using go get and a place to import packages from), but I was unaware of why you need to have the public code in the same place as your own code. Turns out there is no need for it, as explained by @peterSO in the (excellent) answer I accepted below.

Comment: If you're using GOPATH, all packages must be in GOPATH to work. You may be inadvertently mixing module and GOPATH behavior here, but you can save yourself a lot of pain later by just following the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explain why GOPATH is convenient and how it should be used in general?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306183/can-someone-explain-why-gopath-is-convenient-and-how-it-should-be-used-in-genera)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `go help gopath`
>
> Go searches each directory listed in GOPATH to find source code, but
>   new packages are always downloaded into the first directory in the
>   list.

---

`$GOPATH` is a directory list. For example, on Linux,

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/gopublic:$HOME/goprivate
```

`go get` places all downloads in the first directory in the list: `$HOME/gopublic`. Put all your packages in the second directory in the list: `$HOME/goprivate`.

Comment: This is great! So the reason I also want the `$HOME/goprivate` in there is because it enables me to also import from packages that I've written myself? Or are there other reasons to also include `$HOME/goprivate` in the GOPATH?

Answer (score 0):

`GOPATH` is a default directory that the golang toolchain looks at when you're attempting to compile code. It's not *technically* 100% necessary to set a custom one, as if I recall correctly, it defaults to `~/go/`.

As peterSO said above, `GOPATH` is a list and puts packages into the first entry.