# Go: Install package with -u command

Tags: go

I'm trying to install a Go package (https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata#installation) by running this command

```
go get -u github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/...
```

I get this error:

```
package github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/...: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

My GOPATH is set in the ordinary way. I understand this is caused by the -u command... how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your OS, but make sure your `GOPATH` is set in your `.bashrc` (as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21012349/6309)) or least set with

```
export GOPATH=/home/<username>/go
```

That way, other processes (like `go get`) will inherit that variable.

On Windows, you would declare that variable in your user environment variables.

To check what is already set ("[Print Go environment information](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/#hdr-Print_Go_environment_information)"):

```
go env
```

---

If the variable is already set, but a go get -u still fails, then this could be similar to [issue 42](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/issues/42#issuecomment-53274228):

> Your issue is that you have installed go to a location that requires privilege escalation to install to.

Check also your [`GOROOT` and where go is installed](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/issues/42#issuecomment-53290423).

Comment: I've already set it as you suggested above, but it didn't work. Only when I remove -u it manages to install.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. I had assumed I needed -u to be able to run the command-line program, it works.