# How do I fix my GOROOT and GOPATH variables to run go?

Tags: bash, go, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, .profile

### Operating system: Ubuntu 14.04

### lines in the .bashrc (tried both of the following)

```
# GoPath (without goroot)
export GOPATH=$HOME/gowork
```

...

```
# GoPath (with goroot)
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/gowork
```

Note: I tried to set the above environment variables, first in .profile and then in .bashrc as suggested by different people in a different way.

### Tried to run the following code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

### Error message in the terminal

```
go run helloworld.go 
helloworld.go:3:8: cannot find package "fmt" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/fmt (from $GOROOT)
    /home/arif/gowork/src/fmt (from $GOPATH)
package runtime: cannot find package "runtime" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime (from $GOROOT)
    /home/arif/gowork/src/runtime (from $GOPATH)
```

## edit

### go env output

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/arif/gowork"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

### go version output

```
go version go1.3.3 linux/amd64
```

## A hint

I remember that the tar I installed from was go1.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz, which means the go version 1.6 should be shown but my terminal is outputting 1.3.3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21012349/2020002 worked for me, have you tried it?

Comment: And I would suggest removing `GOROOT`

Comment: @OliverQueen , doesn't work in my case, gives me the following error ( go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/lib/go )

Comment: @OliverQueen I tried it both the ways, leaving the GoRoot, and removing it.

Comment: did you restart the terminal after removing GOROOT?

Comment: @OliverQueen, yes, I even restarted the computer.

Comment: Can you show the output of the command `go env` and `go version`?

Comment: I'm gonna edit the question with the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally never have to set `$GOROOT` unless you know why you're setting it.

This assumes a 'normal' installation of Go.  If you've moved the go binary around, or deleted pkg or src folders, your mileage may vary.

Also, make sure an older version of go is not found in your $PATH before the version you intend to use.

In this case @Bangash had to delete the old /usr/bin/go and add /usr/local/go/bin to his PATH environment variable.

[Usually people use $GOROOT](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment) when switching between multiple versions of go.

Please read comments as well as chat for the solution.

Comment: When I remove $GOROOT variable it gives me the following error

( go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/lib/go )

Comment: I have installed it to the default location /usr/local/go, as suggested by golang.org

Comment: I removed the previous installation of go and all of its variables from the .profile and .bashrc, than installed the new one to usr/local/go and set the variables as said in the question

Comment: @Bangash : Provide the output of `go env` or nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: yes, I'm gonna edit the question with the go env's output.

Comment: I edited the question, would you please look at it again.

Comment: ah.. what is the output of `type go`?

Comment: Its ( go is hashed (/usr/bin/go) )

Comment: so, you need to fix your PATH so that /usr/local/go/bin appears before /usr/bin, or you need to remove the go in /usr/bin

Comment: Which of these files should I delete ? (its a screenshot from /usr/bin)
http://i.imgur.com/Vhhs3zf.png?1

Comment: `go`  that's the only one.

Comment: The shortcut / link ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107681/discussion-between-john-weldon-and-bangash).

Comment: How to remove the GOROOT from `go env`. I did unset GOROOT to removed it from shell. but `go env` still shows it.