# Golang - skip SSL / x509 verification and build package?

Tags: ssl, go, compilation

I know nothing about the Go language, I'd just like to use this app on Ubuntu 14:

- https://github.com/mvdan/fdroidcl

Before doing anything, I had to [set the GOPATH environment variable in my ~/.bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001387/how-do-i-set-the-gopath-environment-variable-on-ubuntu-what-file-must-i-edit/21012349#21012349). Then the README says this program is installed with:

```
go get -u github.com/mvdan/fdroidcl/cmd/fdroidcl
```

This passes fine, and an executable is found. In fact, these are the files found in home, where `GOPATH` is `~/go`:

```
$ find ~ -name 'fdroidcl*' 2>/dev/null 
/home/myusername/.cache/fdroidcl
/home/myusername/.config/fdroidcl
/home/myusername/go/pkg/gccgo_linux_386/github.com/mvdan/fdroidcl
/home/myusername/go/src/github.com/mvdan/fdroidcl
/home/myusername/go/src/github.com/mvdan/fdroidcl/cmd/fdroidcl
/home/myusername/go/bin/fdroidcl
```

Nice, but now when I start the initial command:

```
$ fdroidcl updateDownloading https://f-droid.org/repo/index.jar... 
update: could not update index: Get https://f-droid.org/repo/index.jar: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: cannot verify signature: algorithm unimplemented" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "COMODO RSA Certification Authority")
```

This is most likely a failure due to self-signed certificate. A quick fix would be to use `http://` instead of `https://` (in case of `f-droid.org` it is currently possible), so I tried changing `~/go/src/github.com/mvdan/fdroidcl/cmd/fdroidcl/main.go`:

```
var config = userConfig{
        Repos: []repo{
                {
                        ID:      "f-droid",
                        //URL:     "https://f-droid.org/repo",
                        URL:     "http://f-droid.org/repo",
                        Enabled: true,
                },
                {
                        ID:      "f-droid-archive",
                        //URL:     "https://f-droid.org/archive",
                        URL:     "http://f-droid.org/archive",
                        Enabled: false,
                },
        },
}
```

... but the command is actually binary:

```
$ file $(which fdroidcl)
~/go/bin/fdroidcl: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=cd1dc87b54f9023983511ef46fda15a4d88dcb2d, not stripped
```

... which means I'd have to somehow re-build this application from source in order to get those changes in - how would I do that?

Furthermore, there may be other apps with self-signed https certificates that would break, so I'd much rather skip SSL / X509 verification. It seems that, as [golang: How to do a https request with bad certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122159/golang-how-to-do-a-https-request-with-bad-certificate) points out, that one should do in code:

```
tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
tr.TLSClientConfig.InsecureSkipVerify = true
```

... which again requires hacking/recompiling the source code - but isn't there some sort of a environment variable to help that, like [`GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` for `git`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate/19363404#19363404)?

Comment: This is not a question about Go and not really suitable for SO. Of course you have to recompile after changing the source.

Comment: Thank you @Volker - and I'm really sorry for wasting your time. What would you suggest is a better fit for this question? I'll tag it immediately so it is moved to another forum. Btw - of course I have to recompile, that much I know - but using what command, is what I'm asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating the source as you did (in `$GOPATH/src`) you can try re-compiling using the following command:

```
go install github.com/mvdan/fdroidcl/cmd/fdroidcl
```

Comment: Thanks, @JoshLubawy - I would have thought the build command is `go build` or something, didn't quite expect `go install`. Could you maybe expand on where this `install` installs to - is it  `~/go/bin/`; or is there some sort of settings file that could be in the git project dir?

Comment: `go install` does `go build` and puts the resulting binary in $GOPATH/bin (the same place that `go get` puts it)