# VsCode Go setup problems

Tags: linux, go, visual-studio-code

I want to use VsCode for Go programming, but if I try to create/edit a .go file, VsCode forces me too install "gocode command", as you can see in the following:

[image].

When I click on install, the output field shows me these errors:

[image: Errors_1]

[image: Errors_2]

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What is your current GOPATH? Try this in the console: echo $GOPATH

Comment: echo $GOPATH returns /usr/local/go/bin/go

Comment: Your screenshots show that the path is missing the leading /, it looks like usr/local/bin/go

Comment: @MarcelKämper: ` /usr/local/go/bin/go` is the go binary, that can't be the GOPATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says that your GOPATH is relative and should be absolute.

Make sure you read [THIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension) first.

Make sure your GOPATH and GOROOT are defined in absolute paths.

Edit your .bashrc, .profile, .zshrc, etc accordingly:

```
GOPATH=/path/to/a/directory/inside/home/directory
GOROOT=/path/to/you/go/library
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744872/1016425) for more details.

Comment: GOPATH and GOROOT should _not_ be in your PATH