# Error in compiling golang after migrating to centos

Tags: go, jwt, toml

I was migrating my **Golang** programs from windows to Centos 7

It worked perfectly in Windows
but when I tried to **compile on centos** I get errors like

```
main.go:20:3: cannot find package "github.com/BurntSushi/toml" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/BurntSushi/toml (from $GOROOT)
        /root/work/src/github.com/BurntSushi/toml (from $GOPATH)
main.go:15:3: cannot find package "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go (from $GOROOT)
        /root/work/src/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go (from $GOPATH)
main.go:16:3: cannot find package "github.com/gwlkm_service/config" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gwlkm_service/config (from $GOROOT)
        /root/work/src/github.com/gwlkm_service/config (from $GOPATH)
```

kinda new to centos so idk what to do

Comment: Are you using any Go dependency management like `dep` or `go module`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have configured your GOPATH, without Go Module, you can use `go get [package path]` to download imported packages.

```sh
go get github.com/BurntSushi/toml
go get github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go
go get github.com/gwlkm_service/config
```

Comment: if i would ask, where does the system save the file after go get?

Comment: in the `$GOPATH/src`

Comment: oh yeah thanks!
any other way to run that main.go as background process as windows?

Answer (score 0):

Precisely

your go installation on server seems in `/usr/local/go` and
your project is in `/root/work`
so all your dependencies should be either in `/root/work/src` or `/usr/local/go/src`

now coming to action check your `GOPATH` with running `echo $GOPATH` 
assuming it is automatically set to `/usr/local/go/src`
If not then follow - [How do I SET the GOPATH environment variable on Ubuntu? What file must I edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001387/how-do-i-set-the-gopath-environment-variable-on-ubuntu-what-file-must-i-edit)

If everything is ok then in your folder run `go mod init`

this will create mod file which will help you in further installations
look into - https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

then run go get commands as above @beiping96 said

`go get github.com/BurntSushi/toml`
`go get github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`
`go get github.com/gwlkm_service/config`

NOTE - after completing above process you will generate go modules file(same as package.json) and in future you won't need to care about dependencies

Comment: Okay sir thanks.
any way to run the main.go as background process?

Comment: use `pm2` *or*
use nohup *or*
add & in the end of command like `go run main.go &`