# Not able to install cmd version of c4 from github

Tags: go, github, c4

I want to generate `sha512` key for a file, When I looked through internet I found that `c4` can help me to do that thing and when I open it's github repository I am not ablke to found how can I run the `cmd/c4` in my ubuntu terminal. I have installed the `go` in my system and when I clone this `repo`
https://github.com/Avalanche-io/c4.git
And went to path `cmd/c4` there is no `make` file present except five `go` files which are

1. `flags.go`
2. `id.go`
3. `main.go`
4. `output.go`
5. `walker.go`
   I am not able to implement this `cmd` version of `c4` in my `ubuntu` system. Please help.
   As one of the answer has told me to run this command `go get github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/cmd/c4`  I have done this it not producing any error but as written in the answer `now you can use c4 as command` but it's not happening. When I use `c4` ubuntu says  `command c4 not recognized`. So now I just clone the given `repo` in the pc and then run the command `go get *` so inside the `repo` so it was giving following error.

```
package CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md: unrecognized import path "CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md" (https fetch: Get https://CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md/?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md: no such host)
package CONTRIBUTORS: unrecognized import path "CONTRIBUTORS" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package db: unrecognized import path "db" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package doc.go: unrecognized import path "doc.go" (https fetch: Get https://doc.go/?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup doc.go: no such host)
package id: unrecognized import path "id" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package id.go: unrecognized import path "id.go" (https fetch: Get https://id.go/?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup id.go: no such host)
package id_test.go: unrecognized import path "id_test.go" (https fetch: Get https://id_test.go/?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup id_test.go: no such host)
package internals_test.go: unrecognized import path "internals_test.go" (https fetch: Get https://internals_test.go/?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup internals_test.go: no such host)
package LICENSE: unrecognized import path "LICENSE" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package manifest: unrecognized import path "manifest" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package README.md: unrecognized import path "README.md" (parse https://README.md/?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
package store: unrecognized import path "store" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package tree.go: unrecognized import path "tree.go" (https fetch: Get https://tree.go/?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup tree.go: no such host)
package treeslice_bench_test.go: unrecognized import path "treeslice_bench_test.go" (https fetch: Get https://treeslice_bench_test.go/?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup treeslice_bench_test.go: no such host)
package tree_test.go: unrecognized import path "tree_test.go" (https fetch: Get https://tree_test.go/?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup tree_test.go: no such host)
package util: unrecognized import path "util" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

Answer (score -1):

To install go compilable commands, you just go get them:

```
go get github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/cmd/c4
```

This will produce the "c4" binary in your GOPATH/bin.

If you did not configure this, or add it to your PATH variable, you can run it as:

```
~/go/bin/c4
```

Otherwise it's in your path, and you can just run it as "c4".

For a guide on how to configure paths related to Golang, take a look here: [How do I SET the GOPATH environment variable on Ubuntu? What file must I edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001387/how-do-i-set-the-gopath-environment-variable-on-ubuntu-what-file-must-i-edit/53026674#53026674)

Comment: "Then you can run the "c4" command" - after adding `GOPATH/bin` to your `PATH`

Comment: Having your GOPATH/bin is a prerequisite for using go tools. You also need to power on your computer, install an OS, installing Go, and customizing your path settings.

Comment: I tried using it but after running ```go get github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/cmd/c4
``` nothing happens and c4 still not visible. I just clone the repo now and when I run the command ```go get * ```` it shows some ```no such host ```` kind of stuff. please help me.

Comment: I've updated the answer @VinayKumarShukla