# main.go not able to find the package

Tags: go, c4, go-get

Actually I want to use `c4` to generate the `c4 id`  for the video files, So I found the below `repo` which is developed to do this thing, So I clone this `repo`
https://github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/tree/v0.7.0

Now as suggested in this answer from stack overflow: [Not able to install cmd version of c4 from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361012/not-able-to-install-cmd-version-of-c4-from-github)

I execute the following command in my `ubuntu` terminal

```
go get github.com/Avalanche-io
go get github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/id
go get github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/cmd/c4
```

then as they have shown in the example of how to use this `repo`

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "io"
  "os"

  c4 "github.com/avalanche-io/c4/id"
)

func main() {
  file := "main.go"
  f, err := os.Open(file)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer f.Close()

  // create a ID encoder.
  e := c4.NewEncoder()
  // the encoder is an io.Writer
  _, err = io.Copy(e, f)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  // ID will return a *c4.ID.
  // Be sure to be done writing bytes before calling ID()
  id := e.ID()
  // use the *c4.ID String method to get the c4id string
  fmt.Printf("C4id of \"%s\": %s\n", file, id)
  return
}
```

I just copy this same example and created a `main.go` file and when I run this command which they have defined here in their `README.md` https://github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/blob/v0.7.0/id/README.md
The command is ````` go run main.go  ```` Instead of getting the ````` c4 id``` of the file as they have shown in their example. I am getting the following error

```
main.go:8:3: cannot find package "github.com/avalanche-io/c4/id" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/github.com/avalanche-io/c4/id (from $GOROOT)
    /home/vinay/go/src/github.com/avalanche-io/c4/id (from $GOPATH)
```

I don't know about `go` language so it is becoming very difficult for me to solve the problem here, Is there any `go` developer which will help me out.

Comment: Not your fault, since you're just following instructions, but you should never ever use `go run main.go`.  As for your specific problem, it seems the documentation is incomplete and/or outdated. Apparently that package ([github.com/avalanche-io/c4/id](https://github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/tree/master/id)) is deprecated, according to the README. I advice asking on the GitHub issue tracker for the relevant project, since they need to fix their documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`main.go` file is not able to find the package `github.com/avalanche-io/c4/id` inside `/home/vinay/go/src/github.com/avalanche-io/c4/id` , As I can see you have run the following `go get`  commands

```
go get github.com/Avalanche-io
go get github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/id
go get github.com/Avalanche-io/c4/cmd/c4
```

but none of them has name `github.com/avalanche-io/c4/id`
so according to me, You need to execute the following command

```
go get github.com/avalanche-io/c4/id
```

Now just run your main.go

```
go run main.go
```

Comment: Thanks it works. How fool I am to miss this single thing. anyway thank you.