# Unable to run ginkgo bootstrap command on mac

Tags: go, ginkgo

When I run this command

```
ginkgo bootstrap
```

I am getting this error

```
zsh: command not found: ginkgo
```

I have already installed ginkgo using the following command

```
go get -u github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo
```

I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "I have already installed ginkgo using the following command `go get -u github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo`". No you didn't. `go install` is used to install commands. `go get` is used to track dependencies.

Comment: be sure your `PATH` env variable is configured correctly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21012349/2270041

Comment: Even after using go install, the problem persists still. Any idea how to solve this.

Comment: be sure you have the `$GOPATH` env variable setted (just `echo $GOPATH` ) and double check the `ginkgo` is located in the `$GOPATH/bin/ginkgo` path

Answer (score 18):

After installing Ginkgo as described [here](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#installing-ginkgo), for example the latest version:

```
go env -w GO111MODULE=on
go install github.com/onsi/ginkgo/v2/ginkgo@latest
go get github.com/onsi/gomega/...
```

Make sure GO bin is in your PATH:

```
go env GOPATH # /home/user/go
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
```

Now try to run Ginkgo:

```
ginkgo bootstrap
Generating ginkgo test suite bootstrap for temp in:
    temp_suite_test.go
```

Comment: this worked for me.  i only had to start at the "Make sure GO bin is in your PATH" part.  thank you!